# Space between Menus in Tkinter Menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the below tkinter menubar. It all works great, accept the menus within it are all bunched up close together.
Can anyone please tell me if there's a way to add left and right padding between the menus.
I don't mean the separator in the menu items, but padding between the top menus in the menubar, such as between "File", "Edit", "About".

Specifically:
[image]

```
my_menubar = tk.Menu(root, background='#ffffff', foreground='#000000',relief=FLAT,bd=0)  # create menu widget



#-----------------Create dropdown menu "file" in menubar-----------------------------
#ddmenu_file = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0, background='#111111', foreground='#ffffff', relief=FLAT, activeborderwidth=0, activeforeground='black',activebackground='#ADD8E6')    # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_file = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0)    # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_file.add_command(label="New File", command=ddmenu_file_new_file)
ddmenu_file.add_separator()
ddmenu_file.add_command(label="Exit", command=ddmenu_file_exit) # create sub menu item
my_menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=ddmenu_file, font=("",menu_text_size, 'bold'))    #Attach the dropdown menu (File menu) to the menubar


-----------------Create dropdown menu "edit" in menubar---------------------------
#ddmenu_edit = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0, background='#111111', foreground='#ffffff', relief=FLAT, activeborderwidth=0, activeforeground='black',activebackground='#ADD8E6')     # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_edit = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0)     # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_edit.add_command(label="Cut", command=ddmenu_edit_cut)   # create sub menu item
ddmenu_edit.add_command(label="Copy", command=ddmenu_edit_copy) # create sub menu item
my_menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=ddmenu_edit, font=("",menu_text_size, 'bold'))    #Attach the dd menu (Edit menu) to the menubar


#---------------Create dropdown menu "options" in menubar-------------------------------
#ddmenu_option = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0, background='#111111', foreground='#ffffff', relief=FLAT, activeborderwidth=0, activeforeground='black',activebackground='#ADD8E6')  # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_option = tk.Menu(my_menubar, tearoff=0)  # Create dropdown menu (file menu) and assocaite it with menubar. trearoff=0 removes dashed line first item (prevents menu tearoff)
ddmenu_option.add_command(label="Find", command=ddmenu_option_find) # create sub menu item
ddmenu_option.add_command(label="Find Next", command=ddmenu_option_findnext)    # create sub menu item
my_menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=ddmenu_option, font=("",menu_text_size, 'bold'))   #Attach the dropdown menu (Option menu) to the menubar
```

Comment: Here is link. https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-menu/

Comment: Thanks for the reply toyota Supra. Nothing on padding unfortunately :(

Comment: AFAIK, Menus are part of the decoration at least under windows and the underlying OS does not provide a lot of customization for it. What you could do however is to add white-space if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, you don't have control over this. There are no options to modify the space between items on a menubar. On Windows and OSX menus are handled by the OS and tkinter has very little control over them. For unix-based systems, it might be possible to dig into the tk source code and see how the menubar is created, and then set some option database values that might be able to change it.

If all you want is some separation, you can try adding spaces before and/or after the menu names, or use the `compound` and `image` options to add an invisible image with each menu item. However, from a usability point of view you should consider just letting them stay however the OS renders them.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to better show the spacing/padding I'm trying to add. I'm not sure if there's a way to use pack to pack each separate menu in the menubar with left and right padding.

Comment: I think I've got it. Think I need to use widget tk.Menubutton for each main menu ("File" menu, "Edit" menu etc) rather than have them within a tk.Menu. That should allow me to pack the individual menus and add padding between them I think. Is that a recommended way to go about it?

Comment: @Ant This seems to be a valid way to achieve what you want, but it is a different question; strictly speaking. You should consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer if it solves your initial question.

Comment: @Ant: Yes, you can create a menubar using a frame, menubuttons, and menus. I wouldn't go so far as to say it is a recommended way to go. The downside is that they won't behave like native menus, making your app feel a but unusual and slightly more difficult to use.

Comment: @BryanOakley - thanks very much for the info. I think I'll stick with the tk.Menu widget as the recommend choice. Also see online talk of MenuButton potentially becoming deprecated.